# populating a database from a file using c++

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, database

I've searched all over the net and looked in books, but I'm totally stuck.  I'm trying to populate a database using a .txt file, sql and c++.  I know one can use LOAD DATA INFILE, but I must use C++ for this project.

Here is the database table in SQL:

```
create table Employee(
employeeID char(5) not null,
employeeTYPE char(15),
employeeNAME char(25),
hireYEAR integer,
primary key(employeeID)
);
```

Here is the text file to be inserted into the database:

```
E0001 Assistant Joseph 2000
E0002 Assistant Thomas 2012
```

I understand how to connect to the database and I know how to read into a file in C++, however I'm stuck on how to read into a file with the C++/SQL combo. Here is what I have so far for int main (), but any help or links would be so appreciated.  Thank you:

```
int main ()
{
  MYSQL *connect, mysql;
  connect=mysql_init(&mysql); //initialize the instance
  //log in and connect to the database
  connect=mysql_real_connect
  (connect, SERVER, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE, 0, NULL, 0);  //not included for privacy

  ifstream inFile;

  inFile.open ("employee.txt");
  if (inFile.fail())
  {
    cout << "open for employee.txt. failed";
    exit (1);
  }

  while (inFile)
  {
    mysql_query(connect, "insert into Employee values"); //not sure how to do this part...

  }

  inFile.close();
  mysql_close(connect);
  return 0;
}
```

//EDIT WITH ANSWER
Thank you for the help, I have come to understand the problem.
In order to read into the database from a file using C++ embedded in SQL, there are a few syntax ideas that must be known.

For example, to concatenate a string, the "+" character is used. This differs from PHP where the "." character is used. Additionally, in order to utilize the ' character, an escape character \ must be used.

Once you've connected to the database and opened the file using C++, you enter into a loop to read in from the file.

the syntax to store the Insert statement in the string sql:

```
 sql = "insert into TABLE values (\'"+ string1 + "\', \' "
 +string2 + " \', \'" +string3 + "\', \'" +string4+ "\')";
```

Finally, in order to convert the strings to chars, the statement:

```
sql.c_str()
```

must be used as the second argument to mysql_query

Hope this helps someone searching for help with this in the future. I'm a noob, so please let me know if there are any errors in my explanation above.

Comment: You really need to ask a *specific* question, show us what your understanding of how to solve that question is, and show us where you get stuck. "I'm trying to do X. Here's what I have so far." is not a question.

Comment: specifically, how can you read from a text file into a database using c++.  How can one account for the spaces between the input values in the .txt file.  Specifically, the SQL input statement would be for example, "insert into Employee
values
('E0001', 'Assistant', 'Jospeh', 2000),
('E0002', 'Assistant', 'Thomas', 2012); but how could this be translated into insertion using c++.

Comment: Do you know how to read a line from a file? If not, don't need to do that first? If you do, why isn't that in your code? You've made it almost impossible for the people who want to help you to understand what you need help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem you are facing is how to get a mutable string to construct your query.

First include the string stream headers:

```
#include <string>       // std::string
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <sstream>      // std::stringstream, std::stringbuf
```

Then in your loop as you read the data from the file

```
// you should read the data here....
string data1 = ?;// read from file
int data2 = ?;// read from file
string data3 = ?;// read from file

// then you construct the query string
stringstream ss;
ss << "INSERT INTO employees values (" << data1 << "," << data2 "," data3 ")";
mysql_query( connect, ss.str() );
```

Hope it helps ^_^